# Admin Control / Route Issues

Tags: ruby

Right, I've been really struggling with this routing issues.

I have a nested comment section called snippet and this belongs_to :books

Please see my admin index, snippet controller & routes in that order, I've just implemented shallow resources.

This is the current error I'm getting:

> Couldn't find Book with id=2

There is only one book and it has many snippets but I think it's trying to look for the snippet ID rather than the book on approval action. I don't understand why?

```
<h3>Users</h3>
<div class="span8">
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Registered</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to user.full_name, user %></td>
      <td><%= user.email %></td>
      <td><%= user.created_at.to_date %></td>
      <td><%= user.roles.first.name.titleize unless user.roles.first.nil? %></td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#role-options-<%= user.id %>" class="btn btn-mini" type="button">Change role</a>
        <%= render user %>
      </td>
      <td><%= link_to("Delete user", user_path(user), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete, :class => 'btn btn-mini') unless user == current_user %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</div>
<div class="span8">
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Book Created</th>
      <th>Registered</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to book.title, book %></td>
      <td><%= book.created_at.to_date %></td>
      <td><%= render book %></td> 
      <td>Status</td>
<td><%= button_to 'Approve', active_book_path(book) %></td>
</tr>

    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
  </div>

  <div class="span8">
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Book Created</th>
      <th>Registered</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @snippets.each do |snippet| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to snippet.body %></td>
      <td><%= snippet.created_at.to_date %></td>
      <td><%= render snippet %></td> 
      <td>Status</td>
<td><%= button_to 'Approve', active_snippet_path(snippet) %></td>
</tr>

    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
  </div>
```

Snippet_controller

```
class SnippetsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create], :except => [:index, :show]
  before_filter :find_book

 def create
    @snippet = @book.snippets.create!(params[:snippet])
    redirect_to @book
  end      


def approve
   @snippet = Snippet.find(params[:id])
    if @snippet.update_attribute(:approved, true)
    redirect_to users_path
  else
   render root_path
  end 
end

  def edit
    @snippet = @book.snippets.find(params[:id])
  end    

  def update
    @snippet = @book.snippets.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @snippet.update_attributes(params[:snippet])
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def find_book
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Routes

```
Treebook::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#home'
  post "recurly/push"
  get "content/Clerk"
  get "content/Author"
  get "content/Editor"

match '/home' => 'pages#home'
match '/about' => 'pages#about'
match '/contact' => 'pages#contact'  
match '/subscribe' => 'pages#subscribe' 
match '/new' => 'pages#new' 
match "books/:id/activate" => "books#approve", :as => "active_book"
match "/snippets/:id/activate" => "snippets#approve", :as => "active_snippet"


    resources :books do
      resources :snippets, shallow: true, :only => [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

end

  devise_for :admins

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }
  devise_scope :user do
    put 'update_plan', :to => 'registrations#update_plan'
end
  get "profiles/show"

  as :user do
    get '/register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register
     get '/register1', to: 'devise/registrations#new2', as: :registernew
    get '/login', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :login
    get '/logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
  end

resources :users

  as :user do
    get "/login" => 'devise/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
    post "/login" => 'devise/sessions#create', as: :user_session
    delete "/logout" => 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  end

  resources :user_friendships do
    member do
      put :accept
    end
  end

  resources :statuses
  get 'feed', to: 'statuses#index', as: :feed


end
```

Rake Routes

```
    root        /                                      pages#home
            recurly_push POST   /recurly/push(.:format)                recurly#push
           content_Clerk GET    /content/Clerk(.:format)               content#Clerk
          content_Author GET    /content/Author(.:format)              content#Author
          content_Editor GET    /content/Editor(.:format)              content#Editor
                    home        /home(.:format)                        pages#home
                   about        /about(.:format)                       pages#about
                 contact        /contact(.:format)                     pages#contact
               subscribe        /subscribe(.:format)                   pages#subscribe
                     new        /new(.:format)                         pages#new
             active_book        /books/:id/activate(.:format)          books#approve
          active_snippet        /snippets/:id/activate(.:format)       snippets#approve
           book_snippets POST   /books/:book_id/snippets(.:format)     snippets#create
            edit_snippet GET    /snippets/:id/edit(.:format)           snippets#edit
                 snippet PUT    /snippets/:id(.:format)                snippets#update
                         DELETE /snippets/:id(.:format)                snippets#destroy
                   books GET    /books(.:format)                       books#index
                         POST   /books(.:format)                       books#create
                new_book GET    /books/new(.:format)                   books#new
               edit_book GET    /books/:id/edit(.:format)              books#edit
                    book GET    /books/:id(.:format)                   books#show
                         PUT    /books/:id(.:format)                   books#update
                         DELETE /books/:id(.:format)                   books#destroy
       new_admin_session GET    /admins/sign_in(.:format)              devise/sessions#new
           admin_session POST   /admins/sign_in(.:format)              devise/sessions#create
   destroy_admin_session DELETE /admins/sign_out(.:format)             devise/sessions#destroy
            admin_unlock POST   /admins/unlock(.:format)               devise/unlocks#create
        new_admin_unlock GET    /admins/unlock/new(.:format)           devise/unlocks#new
                         GET    /admins/unlock(.:format)               devise/unlocks#show
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                       registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                       registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                       registrations#destroy
             update_plan PUT    /update_plan(.:format)                 registrations#update_plan
           profiles_show GET    /profiles/show(.:format)               profiles#show
                register GET    /register(.:format)                    devise/registrations#new
             registernew GET    /register1(.:format)                   devise/registrations#new2
                   login GET    /login(.:format)                       devise/sessions#new
                  logout GET    /logout(.:format)                      devise/sessions#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                       users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                       users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                   users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)              users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                   users#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)                       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /login(.:format)                       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /logout(.:format)                      devise/sessions#destroy
  accept_user_friendship PUT    /user_friendships/:id/accept(.:format) user_friendships#accept
        user_friendships GET    /user_friendships(.:format)            user_friendships#index
                         POST   /user_friendships(.:format)            user_friendships#create
     new_user_friendship GET    /user_friendships/new(.:format)        user_friendships#new
    edit_user_friendship GET    /user_friendships/:id/edit(.:format)   user_friendships#edit
         user_friendship GET    /user_friendships/:id(.:format)        user_friendships#show
                         PUT    /user_friendships/:id(.:format)        user_friendships#update
                         DELETE /user_friendships/:id(.:format)        user_friendships#destroy
                statuses GET    /statuses(.:format)                    statuses#index
                         POST   /statuses(.:format)                    statuses#create
              new_status GET    /statuses/new(.:format)                statuses#new
             edit_status GET    /statuses/:id/edit(.:format)           statuses#edit
                  status GET    /statuses/:id(.:format)                statuses#show
                         PUT    /statuses/:id(.:format)                statuses#update
                         DELETE /statuses/:id(.:format)                statuses#destroy
                    feed GET    /feed(.:format)                        statuses#index
                 profile GET    /:id(.:format)                         profiles#show
         paypal_checkout GET    /paypal/checkout(.:format)             subscriptions#paypal_checkout
           subscriptions GET    /subscriptions(.:format)               subscriptions#index
                         POST   /subscriptions(.:format)               subscriptions#create
        new_subscription GET    /subscriptions/new(.:format)           subscriptions#new
       edit_subscription GET    /subscriptions/:id/edit(.:format)      subscriptions#edit
            subscription GET    /subscriptions/:id(.:format)           subscriptions#show
                         PUT    /subscriptions/:id(.:format)           subscriptions#update
                         DELETE /subscriptions/:id(.:format)           subscriptions#destroy
```

Full Error Trace

```
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:341:in `find_one'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:312:in `find_with_ids'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
c:in `find'
app/controllers/snippets_controller.rb:39:in `find_book'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:451:in `_run__215511428__process_action__130375634__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:206:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
request_store (1.0.5) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__388865935__call__300725136__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: What does running rake routes tell you?

Comment: That I cannot understand routes, I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `get controller#action`, instead of `match 'controller#action'`

`get "books/:id/activate" => "books#approve", :as => "active_book"`

`get "/snippets/:id/activate" => "snippets#approve", :as => "active_snippet"`